# Parsing an HTML file using Java

Tags: java

How can remove the comments and contents of the comments from an html file using Java where the comments are written like:

```
<!--
```

Any idea or help needed on this.

Comment: This question should be named "How to remove comments from HTML using Java"

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [JTidy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtidy), the java port of HTML Tidy. You could override the print methods of the PPrint object to ignore the comment tags.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have valid xhtml, which a comment posted reminded me of, you should at first apply [jtidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to tidy up the html and make it valid xhtml.

See [this](http://dhillersjavanotes.blogspot.com/2009/03/using-jtidy-to-clean-up-non-valid-html.html) for example code on jtidy.

Then I'd convert the html to a DOM instance.

Like so:

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory newFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = newFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( string ) ) );
```

Then I'd navigate through the document tree and modify nodes as needed.

Comment: Most HTML around is still not XHTML, so JTidy should probably be the first option, not an afterthought.

Answer (score 0):

try a simple regex like

```
String commentless = pageString.replaceAll("<!--[\w\W]*?-->", "");
```

edit: to explain the regex:

- `<!--` matches the literal comment start
- `[\w\W]` matches every character (even newlines) which will be inside the comment
- `*?` matches multiple of the 'any character' but matches the smallest amount possible (not greedy)
- `-->` closes the comment

Comment: A simple regex should be able to do the job - but this one doesn't ... comments are not always opened and closed on the same line. I just found this link on google that seems better: http://ostermiller.org/findhtmlcomment.html

Comment: if you try this, it works. the \w\W catches everything, including newlines, unlike '.'

Comment: Not exactly sure why this is downvoted.  Regardless of whether or not this particular RegEx works, RegEx IS the way to go here.

Comment: No, it isn't. It would remove "comment" from this too: <input type="text" value="<!-- Hello world -->">, which would be incorrect. <!-- doesn't always start the comment.

Comment: good point. is it legal to have < in a string? I'm fairly sure > will throw most browsers.

Comment: Hmm, ones I tried (FF, IE) simply displayed textfield with <!-- Hello world --> text inside. But you're right ... < should not be unescaped I guess. (In XML it would be an error... On the other hand, in XML simple counter-example would be <[![CDATA<!-- hello world -->]]> :-) )

Comment: Or a processing instruction. And native HTML comments have a more complicated syntax than just <!--...--> anyway (eg. multiple instances of ‘--’). Regex is in general not powerful enough to parse even valid XML/HTML, let alone real-world tag soup.

Comment: the question asked specifically about <!-- though. I'm not saying that a regex will work for everything, but that it may be all that you need in some cases

Comment: ah - I didn't really catch the \W bit that would allow for whitespace/linebreaks etc.